# Changing current date time format

Tags: c#

This is how my code is.

```
this.VoucherDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("");
```

I want to display the current date and time in the following format.

```
06/16/2015 16:21
```

Comment: So you want to format it using JavaScript?

Comment: you can use  `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")` trim down if you dont need something .

Comment: Full list of possible format values [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: On a side note: Why you are using the Javascript and html5 tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"

```
this.VoucherDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.VoucherDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.VoucherDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
```

You can also have a look at [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, DateTime format is determined by current thread's culture, which is stored in `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat`. By default, it equals to current user's regional settings. So to change behavior of *all* parameterless `DateTime.ToString()` calls in your code, you can change culture settings.

Secondly, you can specify DateTime format explicitly, as suggested by another answers:

```
this.VoucherDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
```

But generally it's not a good practice.